# Java change default LaF font

Tags: java, swing, fonts, look-and-feel

How can I make the text style in my "Look and Feel" looked like in a Metal LaF?

Bold (a bit) font for uneditable text and subpixel antialiasing for all text.

My Laf - Left; Metal - right

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just coping the font from Metal's LaF. javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel.getUserTextFont() and return that in your LaF class (there are several fonts to copy)

Comment: Or take your font and derive a new type with Font.derive(Font.BOLD); and wrap in a UIFontResource again.

Comment: Font.derive(Font.BOLD) makes the text too BOLD. In the font is not given way to draw it. Full copies of the font does not give the desired result